# Automated email for donations

Tags: email, workflow

I'm a Salesforce developer newbie working in the Non-Profit Starter Pack.  I'm trying to create an automated email so that each time there is a a new Donation entered (which our development director enters manually), an email is sent to the new Contact thanking them for their donation of $xx.

I see code snippets on this site and elsewhere for workflow email, but I don't see where or how to create a new one.  I'm also not clear if I'll need to create a new class or if there is enough functionality built in to the email class to do the trick.

Thanks!

Comment: I might be missing some issue here, so apologies if I am, but isn't the answer a workflow based on the donation entered and then an email task to send the thank you note. I work for a non profit (but don't use the NPSP) and we do exactly this all the time. As I said I don't know any holdups that the NPSP might bring.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I guess I'm not sure how to get started creating a workflow or an email task, and I'm trying to figure out how to get start coding these functions.  Is there a resource that addresses this that you could refer me to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work. I have a Custom Lookup field in Opportunities to find the Contact Email, a WorkFlow rule to create the automated email, and an email template for the automated email to use.  It's all working together now.

Answer (score 0):

First I created a field in Opportunities called Contact_for_Email_c.

For the Workflow rule, first I created the rule criteria, i.e., Opportunity = Donation, etc..  Then I created two immediate actions.

One is the thank-you email alert, which I have triggered when the record is created.  This uses the email template.

Second is a workflow to record that the acknowledgement email has been sent.

Make sure to activate the workflow rules after you create them.

I hope that helps!
Laura

Comment: Since @LauraBayNature is using the NPSP who's solved her problem, your answer seems inappropriate to a 1 year old question since Donations are part of the NPSP. (yes, I know they're equivalent to Opportunity).

Comment: Perhaps, but there seemed to be no harm in sharing the information when asked for it.